# Something buggy on hammer close votes

Tags: discussion

I answered [How to show current loop iteration in click function, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139312/how-to-show-current-loop-iteration-in-click-function-javascript/) and as soon as I'd done it, a banner showed:

> marked as duplicate by Arun P Johny 2 mins ago This question has been
>   asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully
>   address your question, please ask a new question.

And my answer's time showed : `16s ago.`

This itself is buggy as Arun had closed it 2 minutes ago, I shouldn't have been allowed to answer. But to my surprise, Rajaprabhu Arvindsamy too answered it. How?

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." - it's the cache, most likely.